How to remove html native dialog's width
I want to show dialog in full width and height in small screens.  That seems to be working.  However, when I try to remove the width and height (by using unset, auto, or initial) in larger screens it does not work.  Is there a way to do that?


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      dialog {
        width: 100dvw;
        height: 100dvh;
      }

      @media (min-width: 700px) {
        dialog {
          width: unset;
          height: unset;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <dialog open>Hello!</dialog>
  </body>
</html>




"You can use media queries to set the width of the  element to 100% on smaller screens and auto on larger ones. Try the following CSS:

dialog {
width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 700px) {
dialog {
width: auto;
max-width: 100%; /* Or any max-width you prefer */
}
}

This will make the dialog full width by default and then switch to a width based on its content on screens wider than 700px. You can adjust the min-width in the media query to suit your design breakpoints.

Use revert to reset the property back to the UA styles. unset sets it back to the the initial default value which is auto that fills the container's width.
As per spec dialog should have width and height set as fit-content as shown below.
dialog {
  position: absolute;
  inset-inline-start: 0; inset-inline-end: 0;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  margin: auto;
  border: solid;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: Canvas;
  color: CanvasText;
}

I'm not sure what value Safari uses but revert should revert it to whatever value it was using so it will do the default behavior before you set the width for small screens.


dialog {
  width: 100dvw;
  height: 100dvh;
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
  dialog {
    width: revert;
    height: revert;
  }
}
<dialog open>Hello!</dialog>



